# Calling jquery function inside a knockout viewModel declaration. (mainly a syntax issue)

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I have a viewModel called "applications" that contains information of applicants. It looks like this in a knockout-view:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

And I tried to loop through this viewModel and filter out only one element based on a specific condition.

What I am eventually trying to do is, I want to display only one "application" element in a modal.

So, what I have done so far is,

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previewApplicantModal" data-bind="attr: { 'data-applicationKey': application.applicationKey }">
    Preview Application
</a>
```

I added an attribute called applicationKey, so it directly retrieves the "applicationKey" of the applicant.

And I made a jquery function that returns this applicationKey by doing this:

```
                $('#previewApplicantModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
                    var key = $(e.relatedTarget).data('applicationkey');
                    return key;
                });
```

It reads the "data-applicationKey" and returns the corresponding applicationKey.

For example,

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#previewApplicantModal" data-bind="attr: { 'data-applicationKey': application.applicationKey }" data-applicationkey="abd263zqe">
    Preview Application
</a>
```

returns

```
abd263zqe
```

After that, I tried to make a new viewModel called "previewApplication" that only returns the application element that has that "applicationKey". What I did was, I looped through the "applications" viewModel and return only if the "i.application.applicationKey" is equal to the "applicationKey" returned by the jquery function that I wrote above. The code looks like this :

```
            self.previewApplications = ko.computed(function () {
                return ko.utils.arrayMap(self.applications(), function (i) {
                    if(i.application.applicationKey == THE JQUERY FUNCTION THAT RETURNS THE applicationKey)    
                       return i.application;
                });
            });
```

So, I want to return the "application" element that has the same applicationKey as the one that is returned by the jquery function, but I have no idea how to put that in syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying your jQuery event to store the key in your previewApplicationKey observable

```
$('#previewApplicantModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    var key = $(e.relatedTarget).data('applicationkey');
    viewModel.previewApplicationKey(key);
});
```

and then in your comparison function check against that value

```
self.previewApplications = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayMap(self.applications(), function (i) {
        if(i.application.applicationKey == self.previewApplicationKey())    
            return i.application;
    });
});
```

Comment: does "self.previewApplicationKey" have to be "ko.observable(null)" when we first initialize it?

Comment: @user7677413 The value will be undefined by default so you can probably exclude the "null". It does need to be a ko.observable if you're ever going to use it in a binding and want the UI to update accordingly. For this specific situation you probably don't need either it can be a normal variable.

Comment: Oh great. Now I am almost there! If I click the link and try to type "viewModel.previewApplicationKey()" on the console, it gives me the correct applicationKey and when I check "viewModel.previewApplication()" all elements except for the one that has that corresponding applicationKey is undefined. So, now what I have to do is return the only one element that is not "undefined" how can I filter that out?

Comment: I solved this by changing arrayMap to arrayFilter. So when I click the link the "previewApplication" only contains that one single element. Now I am trying to display it on my HTML. What I did is added on my EDIT. Thank you !

Comment: I made it work! Thank you very very much! You saved me!

Comment: @user7677413 I was driving home and couldn't answer for a bit so I'm glad to hear it worked out.